# Equal sign in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

The SQL server doing queries based COLLATE option, so you can define how comparision will be performed (case sensitive or not). You can do it when you creating table or during query execution.

How can I control collation during my LINQ to SQL queries? Will my queries be allways case insensitive when I will do `table.Column == stringValue` comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't work with the COLLATE option much, but will take my best stab at this question.

According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx):

> LINQ to SQL does not consider server settings when it translates queries.

If COLLATE is a database/table/column setting, it should just be set in the database and be ready to go when you connect.

If COLLATE is a connection setting, you can acquire the connection of your datacontext and run the command to set it.  A good place to do this might be in the `partial void OnCreated` method.

Comment: It looks like there is no way to control COLLATE settings for single query.

Answer (score -2):

You have to remember that L2S is a Object Relational Mapping system, so its trying to to compare objects, and translate to SQL.  In L2S, if you want to compare two strings you have to ToLower() both of them for comparison.

Another thing that was a 'gotcha' for me was that in L2S, string comparison will not evaluate correctly if the comparison value you supply is null.  So, in your example, if table.Column is null and stringValue is too, your query will not return the correct results (I am basing this on the assumption that stringValue is a variable defined in your code).  In order to compare a string to null in L2S, you have to compare it explicitly to null: table.Column == null.

check out this [article](http://smsohan.blogspot.com/2008/08/comparing-with-null-in-where-clause-in.html)

Comment: It answered one.  You L2S queries are never case insensitive if you have to use ToLower() for comparison.

Comment: "L2S queries are never case insensitive" is not true

Comment: im not claiming to know it all, so i would like to learn when they arent.

Comment: "out of the box" table.Column == stringValue is case insensitive

Comment: holy crap!  I always just assumed that it would translate for an exact match (following the rules of L2O). So, if you have no control over the database, how do you use L2S to find an exact match in the original query?

Comment: I think best way to change COLLATE settings on every text/nvarchar/char column or on a database to be case sensitive and use String.Equals method for case insensitive comparisons.